# Disable conversion of html entities in CKEditor

Tags: html, ckeditor

I have a textarea containing a text like:

```
Foo &#128247; Bar
```

When I apply CKeditor on that area it correctly displays it as:

> Foo  Bar

Which is fine.

But unfortunately it convertes `&#128247;` to  while doing so.

Can I disable this somehow?

## Edit

I tried [Enities addon](http://ckeditor.com/addon/entities) with the setting `entities_additional` set to `true`.

This setting actually breaks the  character into `&#55357;&#56567;` which is invalid. I'm sure this is a bug and the *Enitiy Plugin* can't handle multibyte characters.

Comment: Why? CKEditor ir content editor and you don't want that the user will "play" with code. I believe that in the "source" mode you will see `&#128247;`

Comment: no, it changes the code.

Comment: Do you mean that in the "source" mode you still got the  icon? Id so, it's a bug (my opinion).

Comment: yes, thats what I mean

Answer (score 1):

By default CKEditor should translate entities with either this [`entities_processNumerical : force`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-entities_processNumerical) or this [`entities_additional:'#128247'`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-entities_additional) setting.

This is however not the case for 4-byte entities as they get destroyed most likely by [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method. 
I have reported this issue here: https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/14588

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, my textarea using CKEditor was adding the encoded HTML tags as plain text, so when I displayed the output on a web page the HTML tags showed up as: <p> in the page and not

which one would not normally see in the browser (one would only see result, the actual paragraph spacing).

I tried all combinations of:

`config.entities = false`

`config.htmlEncodeOutput = false;`

`config.entities = true`

`config.htmlEncodeOutput = true;`

Nothing worked until I realised that I was using the PHP htmlspecialchars() in my form to parse the textarea field.

By removing htmlspecialchars() in my form for that field and setting:

```
config.entities = true;
```

I resolved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I Got a solution, Please use "htmlspecialchars" like echo htmlspecialchars( $content );

This will convert "&" to "&amp ;".